# In junit 4 @Beforeclass @Before and @After tests cases: wrong order of execution

Tags: java, junit4

I am trying to run some simple tests using Junit 4 library and am using `@Before`, `@After`, and `@BeforeClass` annotations. But the problem is `@Before` and `@After` are being executed before the `@BeforeClass`. why is that?

**Code:**

```
import junit.runner.Version;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass2
{
    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Before class");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Before");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("After");

    }

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Test");
        System.out.println("JUnit version is: " + Version.id());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Before
> Test
> JUnit version is: 4.12
> After
> Before class
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. What version of JUnit are you using exactly?

Comment: Before
Test
JUnit version is: 4.12
After
Before class

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: can you update the code import statements

Comment: Also cannot reproduce this. Simple Maven project, JUnit 4.12, your code copy-pasted, results in `-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestClass2
Before class
Before
Test
JUnit version is: 4.12
After
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.133 sec
`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the `@BeforeClass` method as **static**, and using JUnit's annotation (not TestNG). A full code exmaple:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * @author sainnr <p/>27.12.2017.
 */
public class TestClass {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before class");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before");

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After");

    }

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test");

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before class
Before
Test
After
```

As per JUnit documentation: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html.

Comment: JUnit will actually throw a very informative initialization error if a method annotated with `@BeforeClass` is not static, so I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: @sainr
I tried that, though  I am still getting in the wrong order. 

Before
Test
After
Before class

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @Henrik you're right, that's why I've edited my answer and provided the full code example that 100% works on my machine, so the OP could compare. I've also mentioned that it might be an issue with the wrong package name of `@BeforeClass`. @achz please check your imports and make sure you're not using TestNG lib, suddenly